# php forms and url's

Tags: php, forms

I'm having some difficulty with php forms.

I have created a page called 'post_details.php' (this simply displays a photo of a product & description). Each product has a unique id

Within posts_details.php, I have used to include command to include a form. This form allows users to send me feedback regarding the product.

For some reason the form is not workin. Everytime the submit button is clicked, the alert box warns me that I need to complete the form (even if the form is complete)

The last part of line one doesn't seem to work. It's not picking up the post_id

Can anyone please help ??

### post a comment

```
     <form method="post" action="post_details.php?post= <?php echo $post_id; ?>">  


    <table width "600">

         <tr>
            <td>Your email:</td>
            <td><input type="text" name="comment_email"/></td>
        </tr>

         <tr>
            <td>Your Comment:</td>
            <td><textarea name="comment" cols="35" rows="16"/></textarea></td>
        </tr>

          <tr>
            <td><input type="submit" name="submit" value="postcom"/></td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</form> 


 <?php                               

    if(isset($_POST['comment'] )) {

        $comment_email = $POST['comment_email'];
        $comment = $POST['comment'];

       if( $comment_email=='' OR $comment=='') {   

           echo "<script>alert('Please complete form')</script>";

           echo "<script>window.open('post_details.php?post=post_id')</script>";

           exit(); 

       }

       else {

           echo "complete";   
       }

    }    
?>
```

Comment: Use `===` instead of `==` to check if a string is empty.

Answer (score 1):

You have error here

```
if(isset($_POST['comment'] )) {

    $comment_email = $POST['comment_email'];
                      ^
    $comment = $POST['comment']; 
                ^
    ....
```

Instead of $POST it must be `$_POST['comment_email']` and `$_POST['comment']`

Comment: Thanks Vikas ! that's great that worked!   although line one seems to be failing, it's not picking up the post_id. Any ideas?

<form method="post" action="post_details.php?post= <?php echo $post_id; ?>"

Comment: From where you are getting the `$post_id` ?

Comment: `empty("0")` returns `true`. Rather use comparison with `=== ''` to check if a `$_POST` variable is empty.